# Can’t update to 19.04

Tags: updates, 19.04

Trying to update to 19.04 from 18.04 ubuntustudio on a dell pc using the software update tool and it installed 19.04 but would not launch the GUI because it said it could not contact http://changelogs.ubuntustudio.com and that I needed to check my internet connection and proxy settings but I can’t figure out how or where to do that. I am have a stable connection so I dont understand what the problem is. I had to go back to 18.04

Comment: The problem is that skipping releases is not supported and upgrading from 18.04 would have to pass 18.10 which is EOL. If you want 19.04 you'd have to do a fresh install. Or wait until the next LTS release (20.04) and upgrade then, as upgrading from LTS to LTS is supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: I was just using the update prompt that came up when I tried to use the software update. Why would it skip if it’s automatic?

Comment: A thousand apologies, I am on 18.10 after all, so that wasn’t the problem.